# How do I save data permanently so I can access it later in Android?

Tags: android, file, save, storage

Whenever I press the back button my app doesn't call `onSaveInstanceState()` and I can't save data. I'm trying to make a scheduler app and I need to save schedules already set even after I press the back button. I want to dynamically edit a ListView by adding new data from the source file to a stringArray. The problem I'm having is that the file schedules.txt is not saving. Whenever the program opens a new activity the file is now blank.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedules);
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scheduleListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, schedulesList); 
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.v("myapp", "currentlist of files associated with this program are: " + fileList());

    try {

        FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput("schedules.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.v("myapp", "FileOutputStream ran");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

try {
       Log.v("myapp", "first get old schedules call");
       getOldSchedules();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


public void editFile(String format) throws IOException {

    Log.v("myapp", "editFile ran");
    FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput("schedules.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);

    writer.write("hello alex");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    Log.v("myapp", "secondary getoldschedules call");
    getOldSchedules();
}

public void getOldSchedules() throws IOException{

    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("schedules.txt");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis);

    char[] inputbuffer = new char[32];
    reader.read(inputbuffer);
    String data = new String(inputbuffer);
    Log.v("myapp", "data in file reads: " + data);

    reader.close();


}
```

Comment: You might be interested in using SQLite. Nice tutorial: [SQLite Database and ContentProvider](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing immediately wrong with your saving code. The reason `onSaveInstanceState` is not getting called is because it's the wrong tool for the job in this case. That method is called only when an Activity is killed by the system *with the intent of bringing it back*. From the Android documentation:

> One example of when onPause() and onStop() is called and not this method is when a user navigates back from activity B to activity A: there is no need to call onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the system avoids calling it.

Using the back button to navigate away from the Activity is an example of the above scenario - the Activity is being destroyed, so the state doesn't need to be saved for later recovery. `onSaveInstanceState` is designed more for small UI things, like which checkboxes have checks in them, or the text entered in fields - not persistent data storage. You should consider placing the save call into `onPause` (if it's quick), `onStop`, or `onDestroy`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the guide to data storage options on the android developer site, it should tell you everything you need to know: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html